# If $x$ is a set then $\cap x$ is a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Consider the following problem:

(*) If $A$ is a non-empty set, then $\cap A$ is a set.

But I don't think we need the hypothesis "$A$ is non-empty". I can simply write $$\{x \in A \mid \forall y (y \in A ) \rightarrow (x \in y)\}$$ This is a set by the separation axiom and it is the intersection set $\cap A$, isn't it?

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Let $A=\{\{a\}\}$, say. Then $\bigcap A=\{a\}$ but $a\notin A$, so your proposed
definition gives $\emptyset$.

Comment: Could you add a more correct definition of $\bigcap A$? That would make this answer much better in my opinion.

Comment: If $A=\{\{a\}\}$ then according to my proposed definition, we have $\cap A$ is the set of $x$ such that $x=\{a\}$ and $x \in \{a\}$ which gives $a \in \{a\}$. Is this really a contradiction?

Comment: @bbw No, that's not what your definition says. Your definition says that $\bigcap A$ will be the set of _elements of_ $A$ (this is what "$\{x\in A\mid{}$" says), which is an element of all the elements of $A$. And $\{a\}\notin \{a\}$, so by your definition, $\bigcap A$ is empty.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't impose the condition that $A$ is non-empty then $\displaystyle\bigcap A$ is not necessarily a set. Consider $A=\emptyset$. Then, by definition $\displaystyle\bigcap A=\left\{w\mid\forall x(x\in A\to w\in x) \right\}$. If $V$ is the universe of sets, then $\displaystyle\bigcap \emptyset=\left\{w\mid\forall x(x\in \emptyset\to w\in x) \right\}$. But the formula $\forall x(x\in \emptyset\to w\in x)$ is vacuously true. No matter who is $w$. Then, for all $w\in V$ we have that $w\in \displaystyle\bigcap \emptyset$. Therefore $\displaystyle\bigcap \emptyset=V$ and clearly $V$ is not a set.

Comment: thank! but if $A$ is non-empty, is there a problem with my proposed definition?

Comment: Yes. Your definition is wrong. See the answer of Lord Shar the Unknown. The definition of intersection is in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Axiom: $\cup A=\{x:\exists y\in A\,(x\in y)\}$ exists. So let $B=\{x\in \cup A: \forall y\in A\,(x\in y)\},$ which exists by Comprehension (Separation). If $A=\emptyset$ then $\cup A=\emptyset$ so $B=\emptyset.$ If $A\ne \emptyset$ then $B=\{x:\forall y\in A\,(x\in y)\}=\cap A$.